# Is a memory barrier needed (.net x86 or x64) when dereferencing fields?

Tags: vb.net, x86, 64-bit, memory-model, memory-barriers

In code like the following, if Proc1 and Proc2 execute simultaneously on different processors, is it possible for ThingVal2 to get a value other than 5 (e.g. zero)?

```
Class SimpleThing
    Public X As Integer
    Sub New(ByVal value As Integer)
        X = value
    End Sub
End Class
Class ConcurrencyTest
    Dim Thing1 As New SimpleThing(5)
    Dim Thing2 As New SimpleThing(0)
    Dim ThingRef As SimpleThing = Thing1
    Dim ThingVal1, ThingVal2 As Integer
    Sub Proc1()
        Thing2.X = 5
        Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier()
        ThingRef = Thing2
    End Sub
    Sub Proc2()
        ThingVal1 = Thing2.X
        ThingVal2 = ThingRef.X
    End Sub
End Class
```

I know that in a weak model like IA64, there is a real possibility that Proc2 might see ThingRef as having changed but not see field X of Thing2 as having done so.  Does that risk exist for a .Net application running on x86 or x64?  If Proc1 created a new instance of SimpleThing, set its X field to 5, and then set ThingRef to point to it, would that be sufficient to avoid danger, or would it be possible that the new thing might be allocated on a cache line which was shared with something else that the Proc2 thread had accessed?

A common paradigm with multi-threaded code is to construct an immutable object and set a mutable reference to point to it (possibly using Interlocked.CompareExchange).  Is it always safe under x86/x64 to read an immutable type without regard to threading, or can that cause problems?  If the latter, what's the preferred way in vb.net to guarantee reliable behavior?

Also, is there any way of specifying that code must run in a way where such problems could not occur (e.g. limiting execution to a single core on something like an IA64 which could not otherwise guarantee correct operation)?

Comment: Immutable is only guaranteed if the value can be read with one cycle.  Int and bool fall in that category.  Not so sure about long, and definitely not a string.

Comment: @SRM: An immutable object is one which will never change once a reference is made available to anyone else.  The 'SimpleThing' object above isn't immutable, because I'm trying to ask precisely what is and is not guaranteed under the .net x86 and .net x64 memory models.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you gave many questions. I'll try to answer what I know.

-1. ad your code example:

CLR since 2.0 has ordered stores. It means that your ThingVal will always be 5 on x86/x64. For sure. I didn't tried it on a real IA64, but it should work as well on IA64, because CLR should ensure ordered writes on all platforms and should be enough for your simple example.

-2. ad IA64 vs x86/x64:

x86/x64 has a different memory semantics and there is no such risk like on IA64. The only possible problem here is that you are actually using a higher level language and if it used an optimizing compiler (like C++ does) you cannot predict anything without knowing exactly how the compiler do its optimizations. Undocumented: VB doesn't perform any global optimizations etc. so your code should be safe.

-3. ad immutable:

If you really just read it and it is really immutable, it is safe.

-4. ad single core:

You can set the thread affinity. It is a standard property of each thread and defines on which CPUs the thread can run. (Thread affinity setting of .net directly alters the affinity in operating system.) But it makes your program run slowly.

Also, you can switch to C# and use **volatile** keyword. It will help you to live easier, as it makes any changes to volatile variable immediately seen by all CPUs and that in turn will solve all the possible problems you presented here. Unfortunately, VB doesn't provide this keyword.

Comment: I know x86 has ordered stores, but the issue here would be with a load dependency.  Field X from instance2 could have been read in Proc2 before Instance2.X or ThingRef was written.  Under .net, would there be any guarantee that when the code reads ThingRef.X, that it would not simply use the cached value from the read of Instance2.X?  That's a corner case I'd not heard discussed.

Comment: I know it's possible to specify that some threads are only supposed to run on e.g. core #5, but that seems overspecific.  What's really needed is a way of specifying that two or more threads must not be run simultaneously on different processors, and that any time execution moves from one processor to another, the old processor and new processor must flush their caches, in that order.

Comment: Yes, "ordered stores" ensures that when you read ThingRef.X, you either read both new ThingRef and new X, or old ThingRef and old X. It is because your X is inside ThingRef, so you always read ThingRef before X. So it is safe. It could possibly be unsafe even with ordered stores, if you had X1 and X2 inside the same object and they were related to each other.

Comment: @Al Kepp: Is there anything that explicitly documents that a field inside an object instance is guaranteed to be loaded after the object reference, even if that same instance field had just been accessed via another object reference?  By what means would that guarantee be enforced?  Full memory barriers are expensive (and will likely get more expensive in future), but I don't know how to specify narrower constraints.  Evaluating foo.x + bar.y should at most require one barrier (fetch foo, fetch bar, barrier, fetch fetchedfoo.x and fetchedbar.y) but I don't know that a compiler could do that.